# Can't open .pem file in keychain access

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, keychain

So I'm trying to set up an EC2 instance on AWS and I've created a key pair and downloaded the .pem file. However, when I try to open it I get the error message:

[image: Keychain error message]

I've also read about entering the following in the terminal to work around the issue:

```
security import pub_key.pem -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

but this doesn't work either (I get the following error message:

> security: Error reading infile pub_key.pem: No such file or directory).

I've also tried just creating new key pairs but the problem persists.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Isn't this part of the idea of using the keychain to store certificates like this? I want to access my amazon key from other machines.

Answer (score 9):

The keychain extension changed with Sierra. Now it is `login.keychain-db`. You should navigate to where the pem key file is and use

```
security import pub_key.pem -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
```

Comment: Thanks,  Follow up question.  Now what?  If I want to use that stored key to connect, how would I do so?

Comment: Now if you want to connect it should be via ssh. You have two options: 

1. If your instance has a public DNS name use the following command
`ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem my-instance-user-name@my-instance-public-dns-name`

2. If your instance has an IPV6 address use the following command
`ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem my-instance-user-name@my-instance-IPv6-address`.

As it was already mentioned in another comment, the documentation is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html)

Comment: What is the point of putting the pen file in the keychain if you still have to specify it on the command line?   That’s what I do now.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you navigate to terminal to where the pem key file actually is. Then use

```
security import pub_key.pem -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

Comment: If this answer helped please accept it as well. If not let me know why.

Answer (score -2):

The `.pem` file contains your private key used for establishing an `ssh` connection with an Amazon EC2 instance (or any Linux instance).

Do not open (double-click) the `.pem` file. Instead, you will use it with the `ssh` command to connect with your instance, eg:

```
ssh -i yourfile.pem ec2-user@54.1.2.3
```

See documentation: [Connecting to Your Linux Instance Using SSH](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html)

Comment: Using the PEM isn't the problem. Storing it somewhere safe is. That's what the Keychain is for. Why Keychain doesn't allow this is the question.